# Configure beego.Router to serve index.html for AngularJS non-server routes

Tags: angularjs, beego

I have a route beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{}) where it serves the index.html and all other routes are server APIs such as beego.Router("/api/products", &controllers.ProductController{}).

How to configure the beego's router to serve index.html for all others routes that supposed to be handled by ui-router in angularjs such as /products?

beego.Router("/*", &controllers.MainController{}) or beego.Router("*", &controllers.MainController{}) doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved the problem by adding following route to my path

```
beego.Router("/*", &controllers.MainController{})

type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *MainController) Get() {
    c.TplName = "index.html"
    c.Render()
}
```

Simply it returns index.html for any other path and angularjs deal with the rest.

Comment: what was in your MainController?